# React forwardingRef - ref returning parent component of the node that uses ref

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to use `React.forwardRef` to set the `focus` back to `TextField` when the container component is updated. In the container component I am creating a ref like this:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
    ...//rest of the code
  }
```

And I am sending this ref to a child component like this:

```
 <LoginPagePresentation
    ref={this.inputRef}
    error={this.state.error}
    fnr={this.state.fnr}
    onSetFnr={(fnr) => this.setState({fnr})}
    onKeyClick={(key) => this.onKeyClick(key)}
    handleLogin={() => this.handleLogin()}/>
```

In the `LoginPagePresentation` component I am using a `React.forwardRef` to forward the ref to a `TextField` component:

```
   const LoginPagePresentation = React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
      <TextField
          ref={ref}
          autoFocus
          //...other props>
      </TextField>
```

In the container component I would like to set the focus back to `TextField` again, every time the component is updated, but when logging out the inputRef, I get the whole LoginPagePresentation component, and not the `TextField`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
  console.log(this.inputRef.current);
}
```

This the log I get, which is the `LoginPagePresentation`:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here, how can I set the ref properly to `TextField` so that I can set the focus again to it?

Comment: Are you wrapping `LoginPagePresentation` with the `withStyles` HOC?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the `TextField` component is from `material-ui`? According to the [docs](https://material-ui.com/api/text-field/#props) the correct prop to get a ref to the underlying `input` element is `inputRef`:

```
<TextField
    inputRef={ref}
    autoFocus
    //...other props>
</TextField>
```

Also the actual DOM node can be accessed via `this.inputRef.current`. Also see [Accessing Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#accessing-refs):

> ### Accessing Refs
>
> When a ref is passed to an element in `render`, a
>   reference to the node becomes accessible at the `current` attribute of
>   the ref.
>
> ```
> const node = this.myRef.current;
> ```
>
> The value of the ref differs
>   depending on the type of the node:
>
> - When the `ref` attribute is used on an HTML element, the `ref` created in
>     the constructor with `React.createRef()` receives the underlying DOM
>     element as its `current` property.

Comment: Yes, I am using material-ui. I have changed it to inputRef, but I am still getting the same component logged out, and not the input field.

Comment: @Leff Oh, I see you are logging `this.inputRef` instead of `this.inputRef.current`. The current ref has to be accessed via the `.current` attribute of the ref.

Comment: sorry, I did add current later, but I wasn't getting the input prop, will fix this in the question

Comment: @Leff But with both changing to `inputRef={ref}` and `.current` it should work. See this minimal live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/misty-rain-uchlj

Comment: yeah, I am not sure why it is not working after fixing all this. I wonder if it is because I am using material-ui withStyles HOC, that it is not working?

Comment: Ah, it works fine when I change <LoginPagePresentation ref={this.inputRef}> to <LoginPagePresentation innerRef={this.inputRef}